# JPA JoinColumn for foreign keys belonging to the table behind its member entity

Tags: jpa, foreign-keys

I have tables `table_a` and `table_b` and foreign key `table_a_id` references the primary key `id` in `table_a`.

Now I have two JPA entities, `A` and `B`. `A` contains a reference to `B`.

```
public class A {

    ...

    @JoinColumn(name="table_a_id")
    private B b;
}
```

This throws exceptions saying that column `table_a_id` cannot be found in `table_a`. I know JPA is looking for a foreign key `table_a_id` in `table_a` but how can I resolve this problem without moving the foreign key to `table_a`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have `@OneToOne(mappedBy = "a")` in `A`, and `@OneToOne` with `@JoinColumn` in `B`. The owning side of the relationship is the one where foreign key is, that would be `B` in this case. `"a"` in mappedBy is the name of the field of type `A` in class `B`.

**EDIT**

In case of unidirectional relationship, when foreign key is in target table, according to [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne), if you put `insertable = false` and `updateable = false` in `@JoinColumn`, that will instruct the JPA provider to look for foreign key in the target table.

Comment: I know this relationship but I specifically don't want `B` to know about `A`'s existence if that's possible.

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne#Target_Foreign_Keys.2C_Primary_Key_Join_Columns.2C_Cascade_Primary_Keys

Comment: See updated answer, actually exactly what @AlanHay suggested in the posted link.